# Will Python code written in Windows be compatible with Linux?

Tags: python

I would like to write some Python code on Windows using PyQt. However, before doing so, I would like to confirm whether the code I write in Python will be compatible. Although the compiled program may not work due to different platforms, would there be any issues with the *.py files that I write on Windows compared to Linux?

I have been attempting to install PyQt on my Mint system, but I am unsure of the problem. This is why I would like to explore this option.

Moreover, I would like my code to be functional on Raspberry PI.

Comment: QtPy?  Do you mean PyQt?

Comment: Yes PyQt. Thanks for clearing that up :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly, yes, as long as you keep to using the tools Python provides you and don't write code that is platform specific.

Use `os.path.join()` to build paths, for example. Open files in binary mode when you deal with binary data, text mode when it's text data. Etc.

Python code itself is platform agnostic; the interpreter on Linux can read python code written on Windows just fine and vice versa.

The general rule of thumb is to pay attention to the documentation of the modules you are using; any platform specific gotchas should be documented.

Comment: I'd like to use PyQt for GUI development because that is a must. Here's a bit on the project requirements:

I'm using it to build not-too-large applications (for use in developing countries) that have a database and can hopefully run on the Raspberry Pi. Simple but not too simple.

If I build it on windows apart from building paths (something I have had to be careful with on Java as well) what else should I be worried about? I've experimented with JavaFX and while it was good it was a bit too much of a resource hog. I'm hoping Python will be better.

Any thoughts on the above?

Thanks again!

Comment: That is too vague *and* broad to comment on in detail. You'll need to just test your code; most of it will run out of the box, sometimes there will be unexpected gotchas that you didn't expect to see, where Windows does it one way and the rest of the world another. But for the most part, things Just Work.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the comments! I'll just give it a go then!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your code does.  Most packages work in both windows and linux however some such as [signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) only work in windows and are not portable.  But in the python docs it will say what platforms a given package works in.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! My experience is only with Java and I just wasn't sure.